# How to use remote desktop connection after Open VPN setup from TPLINK?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, remote-desktop, openvpn

I have a TP-Link router that allows me to create OpenVPN directly from the router (192.168.0.1). There are 100s of videos online on how to set up the VPN, export the configuration file, and install the VPN client on the remote computer. But I want to know how to remotely access one of my computers on my home network after the VPN is set up. From a remote computer as you can see it is connected to the VPN:

[image]

However, from this remote computer I cannot even ping my home computer where File and Print Sharing as well as Remote Desktop Connection is enabled. I saw one video which says that I still need to turn on Port Forwarding to my Default Gateway IP address but it does not allow me to do so:

[image]

It gives the error The IP address cannot be the same as the LAN IP address. Please enter again

Comment: Such a port-forwarding rule makes no sense in general (what it describes is exactly the same as _not_ having a port-forwarding rule), but there shouldn't be any need for port-forwarding rules in your case specifically, either. Instead I'd be looking at the firewall rules... Does TP-Link's VPN give out IP addresses from your LAN range, or from a separate range? If it's a separate range (which would be the usual mode), could it be that your own computer's firewall blocks the packets? (The built-in Windows Firewall has quite a few "same subnet only" rules.)

Comment: I turned off the firewall in my home computer to see if that is blocking but I still cannot ping my computer

Comment: I changed my default gateway to 10.8.0.1 when using Remote Desktop Connection and it worked. So basically the problem was that it was using the preferred DNS in the client instead of the 10.8.0.1 which was needed.